# Change registration link

Tags: php, wordpress

In a plugin that I am using there is a 'register' link that takes a user to default wordpress registration.

This is the code:

```
$output .= '<p>'.sprintf(__('You need to <a href="%s">login</a> or <a href="%s">register</a> to bookmark/favorite this content.','wpb'),wp_login_url( get_permalink() ), site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink())).'</p>';
```

What change do I need to make to link it to my custom registration page - example.com/register?

Comment: I think you need have your URL here "site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=' . get_permalink())" change this to your URL it replace %s in anchor tag for register

Comment: Also there you can use the hook to change this if plugin is providing hook to change the default functionality

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work!